# Trying to Pass JavaScript variable to PHP using AJAX but get 'Undefined index'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

I apologise if you think this might be a duplicate but I've tried everything I've come across and the problem persists - it's driving me mad!

I basically want to pass a JS variable to a PHP variable whenever a key is hit.

This is a simplified version of how my PHP file is set up (located at `http://localhost/quiz/index.php`)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <?php
                $uid = $_POST['userID'];
                echo $uid;
            ?>
        </p>
        <script src="js/site.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in the site.js file I have the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(document.body)
.keyup(function() {
    var userID = "Jim";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/quiz/index.php',
        data: { userID : userID },
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("success!");
        }
    });
});

});
```

Of course, I am wanting the JS variable userID value ('Jim') to output in the paragraph when a key is pressed, but it only ever shows:

```
Notice: Undefined index: userID in C:\xampp\htdocs\quiz\index.php on line 66
```

However, when a key is pressed the "success" alert pops up.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here? I'm using Xampp if that's relevant!

Thanks!

Comment: Try ` data: { "userID" : userID },` instead of ` data: { userID : userID },`.

Answer (score 2):

You need two PHP files (or one with some branching logic).

- One to provide the HTML document that loads the JS
- One to provide the Ajax response

You are getting the error because the `userID` is not submitted in a POST request to load the initial page.

Then you need to modify your JavaScript so that it does something with `data` instead of just alerting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Although I am even more confused now! What goes in the file to provide the Ajax response? (Sorry, I am very inexperienced with Ajax)

Comment: It should be a program that reads the data you post to it, does whatever you want to do with that data, and then responds with whatever you want to tell the browser in response to that data. (in this case, it would just output `$_POST['userID']`, which is pointless because the browser already has that information, but you did say you were simplifying)

Comment: I apologise for my noob questions but I'm still at a loss as to what to do next. I just want to send that JS variable value to the PHP variable. How do I submit `userID` in a POST request as you suggested?

Comment: I understand why the error appears initially (because the PHP variable isn't set initially), but when a key is pressed, shouldn't it then receive the JavaScript value? Can you point me in the right direction for what I need to do?

Comment: It does — but that's a *different* request, and a different response (which is returned to the XMLHttpRequest object). It doesn't overwrite the current page. The whole point of Ajax is to *not* overwrite the current page.

Comment: Okay I've created a separate logic.php file in which I echo the PHP $uid variable. This outputs 'Jim' in the console when a key is pressed, but I'm still confused as to how I can output this PHP variable in my original `<p>` tag?!

Comment: `createTextNode`, `appendChild`, et al

Comment: But that's through JS? The whole point of this is so I can echo the PHP variable!

Comment: The point of Ajax is to use JS to send data to the server. Then to get some data back from the server (which can be generated using PHP if you like). Then to use JS to do something (usually adding it to the document) with that data. If that isn't what you want to do, then don't use Ajax.